# Как можно избежать двух одинаковых имён классов при наследовании одного от другого

Tags: php, java, c#

Я написал класс `EmailInputField`, который содержит общий функционал для поля ввода электронной почты. Этого функционала когда-то может хватить, а когда-то - придётся наследоваться.

Теперь, у меня есть класс формы входа `SignInForm` и в нём нужно создать наследника от `EmailInputField`. Поля ввода всего два, поэтому, возможно, называть наследника `SignInFormEmailInputField` не обязательно. Но имя `EmailInputField` уже тоже занято.

Как следует поступать в таких случаях? Вы можете привести пример на любом из языков, указанном с тэгах.

Comment: А какое поведение добавляется в наследнике?

Comment: В `SignInFormEmailInputField `? Любое, какое пожелает пользователь библиотеки (я сам об этом заранее знать не должен).

Comment: Вот пусть пользователь библиотеки и мучается, придумывая новое имя.

Comment: К каждому уровню наследования добавляйте постфикс EmailInputField_level1, EmailInputField_level2, EmailInputField_level3 и будет Вам счастье. Сведущие люди говорят, что натуральный ряд бесконечен, так что Вам гарантированно хватит номеров.

Answer (score 1):

Странный вопрос. Придумать название класса настолько сложно, что про это надо писать на SO? 
Ну хорошо, я помогу вам: `AnotherEmailInputField`, `SecondEmailInputField`, `MailInputFiel`, `FieldForEmailInput`.

**UPD:** Наиболее подходящие имена наверное какие-нибудь `MyEmailInputField` либо `EmailAutorisationField`.

Comment: CustomEmailInputField

Comment: `YetAnotherEmailInputField`, `AnotherOneEmailInputField`